# Why is my DriveImage XML restore process so slow?

Tags: driveimagexml

I’m currently trying to migrate my parents’ computer to Windows 7 (from Windows XP).

Initially, I backed up their hard drive to a DriveImage XML image on an external hard drive. I now realise I should have created a bootable copy of their hard drive on the external drive, because I need to boot their old system to extract some details that I can’t get from the files alone.

I’m attempting to restore the image to another external drive. It’s been going for 20 minutes, and it’s only 2% complete.

Their original hard drive had a capacity of 290 GB, but was less than 10% full. I backed it up to a FireWire 400/USB 2 external drive. I’m attempting to restore that to a FireWire 800 drive. The FireWire 800 drive is plugged into their computer, and the FireWire 400 drive is plugged into the FireWire 800 drive.

I know they‘re external drives, so they’re not going to be super-fast, but at this rate it’ll take 20 hours to restore the image, and that doesn’t seem right.

Comment: DriveImage XML is extremely slow.  It's the main reason I stopped using it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s just slow. It was faster on my MacBook Pro than it was on my Mac mini.